# Implementing inline css in react

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to implement inline css on an input element in a react project. The style attribute that I added in the jsx is not rendering. I have checked the App.css and index.css files and there is nothing that would override this. Does anyone know why this isn't working? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: This has been solved, after reading the comments from  jnpdx, Shivam, and Sayog, I was able to edit the FormInput file and it's working now. Thanks everyone for your help!!

```
    return (
            <div id="recipe">
               <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <FormInput style={{width: "250px"}} type="text" name="Name" handleChange={handleChange} />
                    <FormInput style={{width: "250px"}} type="number" name="time" display="Prep Time (in minutes)" handleChange={handleChange} />
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Recipe" />
                </form>
            </div>
        )
```

Comment: `<input/>` doesn't support many of the custom css

Comment: You're not showing the code for `FormInput`, but it is possible that it doesn't use or pass on a `style` prop.

Comment: This style is applied on `FormInput` not on `input`, inspect the DOM and you will know

Comment: You have `FormInput ` as React Component and Inline styles on `React Component`  do not work.  Use `styles` on HTML Elements.

Comment: "I can't move this stying into a css file because there are other forms in the project which I don't want to change." You know you can use `classname` and `id` attributes and selectors to target specific elements, right? can you share the `FormInput` component so we may see how it handles passed props? A lot of component libraries will have a specific prop for passing props to the underlying DOM element.

Comment: Thank you so much, jnpdx, Shivam, and Sayog for pointing out the obvious, which I had missed!